How can I install packages using the startup command in Azure App Service?
I'm trying to install two packages via the startup command, as shown in the screenshot.


However, I'm getting the following error messages in the console.
When I run the commands myself in the SSH it works fine.
2024-06-23T21:13:54.129973640Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-06-23T21:13:54.449210327Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-06-23T21:13:54.449244227Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -bindPort 8080 -startupCommand '/home/start.sh; apache2-foreground;'
2024-06-23T21:13:54.558009274Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-06-23T21:13:54.559142283Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-06-23T21:13:54.559917389Z Build Operation ID: 4d038af9-0ec6-4199-8974-471088a62879
2024-06-23T21:13:55.055261448Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-06-23T21:13:55.238603476Z E: The update command takes no arguments
2024-06-23T21:14:15.474124654Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.478284583Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.478300083Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/dbus-user-session_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.478305483Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/f/ffmpeg/libavutil56_4.1.10-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.478309783Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/f/ffmpeg/libswresample3_4.1.10-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.478313883Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec58_4.1.10-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.481242303Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.64.0-4+deb10u3_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.481260603Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/poppler/libpoppler82_0.71.0-5+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.481284403Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/p/python3.7/libpython3.7_3.7.3-2+deb10u4_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:15.481289003Z E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
2024-06-23T21:14:17.427880704Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 146.75.74.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:17.428726110Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 146.75.74.132 80]
2024-06-23T21:14:17.429575816Z E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


Can you please share more details about the issue

How you are setting the 2 commands,can you please share your startup command screencap?

@Harshitha the screenshots are now included.

What does your startup.sh contain?

@Harshitha the same as in the screenshot.

Did u check oryx-manifest.toml file in any of the deployed files ?

Place the startup.sh file in the root directory,change the path in startup command and check once.

I fixed it by adding #!/bin/bash to to start of the start.sh file.


2024-06-23T21:14:15.474124654Z E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.24-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.190.132 80]

The error clear says that it is unable to found the debian in the given link.

To install any packages using the  .sh script instead of apt-get commands, install them with wget download links.

You need to use wget and link to the tar file to download the particular version.

I got the tar file of libreoffice from the below link
Index of / (documentfoundation.org)


https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/24.2.4/deb/x86_64/


Select the required version from the above list.

Thanks @Ravi Raive for the commands.
startup.sh file:
wget https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/24.2.4/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.2.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

tar xvf LibreOffice_24.2.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

cd LibreOffice_24.2.4_Linux_x86-64_deb


Check the deployed packages in the newui.


